# jQuery Datepicker does not work in dynamic element

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I have a problem. jQuery Datepicker does not work in a dynamic form, so you can't pick a date. Here is my demo link http://gestionale.odoyabooks.com/sum.php.

JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.input_date').on('click', function() {
    $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker({showOn:'focus'}).focus();
        });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST">

<div class="yes">
    <div id="cost1" class="clonedCost" style="display: inline;">
        <table  border="0">
          <tr>          
            <td><label class="date" for="date">Date</label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input class="input_date" id="date" type="text" name="date[]" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="addDelButtons_cost"><input type="button" id="btnAdd" value=""> <input type="button" id="btnDel" value=""></div>
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that when you bind the event initially, the new field doesn't exist.

By applying the on click to the body, with the selector `.input_date`, it should attach the event to the new element in the dynamic form.

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click','.input_date', function() {
        $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker({showOn:'focus'}).focus();
    });
});
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/A9Wb9/)**

---

### A better way:

You should initialize the datepicker for the field when you create the element.

```
$(function() {
    $('.input_date').datepicker();
});

function createNewDatepickerInput() {
    var $newInput = $('<input type="text" name="date123" class="input_date" />');
    $newInput.appendTo("form").datepicker();
}
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hYEss/)**

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating things. I don't see why you need to destroy it, re-initialize it and focus after clicking the input box...

Comment: @Webberig - I left the code inside unchanged. I just changed the event binding, since I believe that is where the problem is.

Comment: i beleive it is better to leave the OPs code unchanged. although mentioning any flaws as a comment helps the guy understand what else he might be doing wrong

Comment: I hereby mention that the OPs code + your answer is overcomplicating things. You just need to call datepicker() after creating the input field, not mess around like that on a click event...

Comment: DesignerGuy@ it does not work. shows an error like Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentDay' of undefined

Comment: @user1652747 - The first or second way I describe above? Also, what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jQuery latest version

Comment: No it does not work. shows again jquery ui Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentDay' of undefined

Comment: I'm not seeing any error with either (using jQuery 2.0.2 and jQuery UI 1.10.3)

Comment: Thanks! works great for me! both in  `Chrome` & `FF` :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you're destroying/re-initializing the datepicker. 
You simply need to call .datepicker() after creating the element. For example:

```
function createInput() {
    $('<input type="text" name="date" />').appendTo("form").datepicker();
}
```

Edit:
Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xEmJu/